# Making service NOT launch at boot

Tags: linux, linux-mint, boot, services, init.d

**Context**

> I made a service in init.d to be launched at boot (let's call it the *primary service*). And I updated `update-rc.d primaryservice defaults`
>
> This service calls 2 scripts (2 different task domains). I decided to make 2 *sub*-services (with start/stop) and to call them from the primary service:

```
#!/bin/sh -e 
...
case
  start) 
  service start subone
  service start subtwo   
;; ...etc...
esac
```

**Question**

**how to not call the 2 subservices at launch ?** but still be able to use `service subservice-one start`
e.g.

Comment: Which version of linux are you using? The details of the solution could change.

Comment: Hi @andcoz, Im using **Linux Mint 17.2 (based on Ubuntu, based on Debian)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must also use the `update-rc.d` command. There is the `remove` option to remove it from the boot sequence. The script will remain in the `init.d` directory and you are still able to start and stop them with the `service` command.